# Control border and background color of a LinearLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have created a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutProfit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:minWidth="0px"
    android:minHeight="50px"
    android:background="@drawable/list_divider_full">
```

Now I want to control the background color and the border. I use this line to control the background color:

```
LayoutProfit.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

and this line to control the border:

```
LayoutProfit.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_divider_top_sides);
```

But it seems like it is or the color or the border. How can I control both of them, so they are both visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `LayoutProfit.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_divider_top_sides);` it will override your LinearLayout background (`"@drawable/list_divider_full"`), thats why you're losing the color you set.

I recommend putting LayoutProfit inside an framelayout with android:background="@drawable/list_divider_top_sides. 
Make sure to add padding with the size of the border defined in list_divider_top_sides.

Comment: And then change the color of the linear layout?

Comment: Yes, although if merging both drawables is an option, Cherry Bu answer is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control LinearLayout border and background color, I suggest you can use one xml to set these.Creating border.xml in drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <!-- border color -->
 <item>
<shape>
  <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
</shape>
```

```
<!-- background color -->
<item android:bottom="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:left="4dp"
      android:top="4dp">
<shape>
  <solid android:color="#ff3235" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/LayoutProfit"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="20"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/border"       
>
```